# 'jt' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, path, jupyter

Trying to change theme of Jupyter notebook but running into difficulty after successful install.

I run:

`jt-t chesterish`

> 'jt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I know its related to not setting the environmental path somehow. But I have tried using SETX PATH but still didn't work and found not other solution thus far. I have before set up python so I can directly type "python" to get it on the command line but doesn't work for anything else like "jupyter".

Comment: have you installed the [jupyterthemes package](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes#install-with-pip)? `pip install jupyterthemes
 ` or `conda install jupyterthemes` if you are using `conda`

Comment: Edit: Yes, I've installed jupyter and jupyter themes successfully

Comment: ah, `jt-t` is not valid, the first command should be `jt` then the `-t` flag. put a space separating `jt` from the `-t` flag: try `jt -t chesterish`

Comment: Thanks @davedwards , resolved the issue - spacing was partially the issue but it was more related to not properly setting up the environmental variable, once I set that up it was all good.

Answer (score 1):

Even if ı have installed the jupyterthemes and upgrade it, ı have the same issue when ı write down the command (!jt -t [themename]) into one of the jupyter notebook's cells. The solution that ı have found is open up the Anaconda prompt and after installing the jupyterthemes, write the command (jt -t exampletheme) and restart the jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using a conda environment with Python 3.7 installed. After I switched the kernel to the original standard "Python 3" kernel with Python 3.9 install, then the jt commands worked for me. Not sure if it was an environment issue or a python version issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that 100% work.

1- Go to Path C:\Users\ **UserName** \AppData\Roaming\Python\ **Installed Python Version** \Scripts

2- Press SHIFT & Right-Click in the Path Folder

3- Choose Open PowerShell Window Here.

4- Enter .\jt.exe -l # To see the list of themes

5- Enter .\jt.exe -t **theme-name**

6- Wait for installation , Then **Restart** Anaconda

7- Enjoy!